# jQuery cookie plugin: Setting a cookie for a year and after closing browser and re-opening - the cookie is gone

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am trying to save a cookie using [jQuery Cookie Plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/).

setting this for a year this way:

```
// Set a flag 
jQuery.cookie('coo_flag', 1, { expires : 365, path:'/' });
```

Getting me this result:

[image]

Clearly stating that the cookie is expiring next year from the day it has been created.

When I close the browser and reopen it, the cookie disappears (together with all cookies saved that way).

Any idea why this is happening?

- Running this on a Wordpress website.
- Tested on Chrome and FireFox web browsers.

Comment: Do you have a setting in your browser to clear cookies/cache when closing? Something some developers do while developing their code... See settings -> Advanced -> Content Settings -> Cookies - make sure you have the 1st radio selected and not the 2nd. Also make sure you don't have any exceptions in 'Manage Exceptions' that will clear cookies.

Comment: well doesn't make scene since this was tested by 2 different browsers.@Darren

Comment: Well, makes perfect sense with the information you have provided. And are both browsers clearing cookies? And have both browsers had their settings checked?

Comment: It's not because it's my personal PC and I have never set this :) anyway.. I have checked my settings following this: http://www.howtogeek.com/137681/how-to-automatically-clear-private-data-when-you-close-your-browser/

And this is not checked on both of my browsers.

Comment: Unable to replicate: https://jsfiddle.net/wxezxd83/. If this doesn't work for you then it is 100% down to your browser settings and/or the cookie being cleared elsewhere in your code base

Comment: And if it's not your browser settings then you have something else in code/running to clear these cookies. As Rory suggests, this isn't reproducible.

Comment: @Darren you're taking this too personally buddy, I'm sorry <3

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I tested this both on Chrome and FireFox and I still get that same result.

Comment: Sounds like your browser is set to clear cookies then.

Comment: I tested this on IE and it actually saved the cookie O_O 
I checked Chrome and FireFox settings again and I don't see anything fishy. 
What other way can a browser like chrome of ff decide to delete cookies?

Comment: Tested on my PC at home + other employees and you were right. 
You can comment an official answer i you like

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot find any browser settings preventing this, perhaps trying it using plain old vanilla javascript, just to see if that works, so something like this:

```
        function setCookie(sName, sValue, nDays) {
        var expires = "";
        if (nDays) {
            var d = new Date();
            d.setTime(d.getTime() + nDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
            expires = "; expires=" + d.toGMTString();
        }
        document.cookie = sName + "=" + sValue + expires + "; path=/";
    }
```